# what is the mathematical name of a bended cylinder

Tags: geometry

what is the mathematical name of a bended cylinder ?

I am refering to this kind of object : https://d3p8pcjf51nlqw.cloudfront.net/data4/SH/NV/MY-20332273/angle-pipe-250x250.jpg

The shape could be described as a tube or cylinder bended in the middle to form an angle

Comment: I'm tempted to call it an [elbow joint](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1242&bih=612&q=elbow+joint&oq=elbow+joint&gs_l=img.3..0l10.28.1878.0.1938.12.7.0.0.0.0.500.830.3-1j0j1.2.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..10.2.830.KSsXLGSwZEQ#tbm=isch&q=elbow+joint+pipe) but that comes from fields outside of mathematics.

Comment: Also, another promising directions is this: a torus is $S^1\times S^1$, the product of two circles, or if you like, a type of surface of revolution you get when you move a circle along a circle. If you replace the moved circle with another shape, you get a [toroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroid). But what if instead of rotating in a circular path, you have something fancier, and the thing you are rotating is still a circle? That looks a bit like what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this object has a specific mathematical name. It consists of two cylinders and a part of a [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus).

Comment: Thank you, I was suspecting it but was hoping there was a name that would make it easier to research online.